# How can a SEL, defined to return id, represent a method that returns a double?

Tags: objective-c, types, selector, return-type

In Objective-C there is a type named `SEL`. It's defined like this:

```
id (*SEL)(id self, SEL _cmd,...);
```

but if we make a method whose return type is `double`, the `id` type is not good to use.

How can the Objective-C runtime work with this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, in general a selector is created by typing @selector(methodName), id (*SEL)(id self, SEL _cmd,...); is the general method declaration.

Comment: @LuavisKang that's not the definition of `SEL`.

Comment: @jbat100 his question is "How can an Objective-C method return a double while `SEL` returns `id`?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SEL` is defined as `typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;`, so you are wrong.

`SEL` is a type used to store a selector, which basically is the "name" of a method, along with some other information.

---

Anyway,

In the case of a `double` return type, Objective-C will simply return a double. It doesn't care about how `SEL` and `id` are declared. (Just like `printf` but the other way around: return value instead of function arguments.)

The implementation of the `+[A a]` method in this sample program:

```
@interface A

+ (double)a;

@end

@implementation A

+ (double)a {
  return 1.0f;
}

@end

int main() {
  double b = [A a];
  return 0;
}
```

Gives this assembly output (which is a function with a generated name you don't know: you can't just call it by its name*):

```
Leh_func_begin0:
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movabsq $1, %rax  ; <-- moves 1.0f into the register
    cvtsi2sdq %rax, %xmm0 ; <-- converts quadword integer to double precision
    movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    popq %rbp
    ret ; <-- returns control
    ; afterwards, the _main function gets the return value from the register
Leh_func_end0:
```

It just returns a `double`, even if a `double` needs more bytes than `id`. It isn't translated to C in between, so this is no problem. Note that the returned values of Objective-C methods are **not type-safe**.

The main function calls `_objc_msgSend` (which calls the "nameless" function pointed to by the `IMP`*) and puts the return value of it into `b`.

---

*the address of that function is stored in the method definition as a variable of type `IMP`. An `IMP` ***is*** defined `id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...)`.